# Azure Deployment of nodejs bot built in botframework sdk4 in es6

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, botframework

I have developed a bot in botframework sdk4 using nodejs transpiled from es6 to es5 with the help of babel. The bot works fine locally and I am able to perform all functions. 
This is how my folder structure looks after transpiling my es6 to es5 [Folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNmfZ.png)

To deploy the bot I am following these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-03.

**The deployment to azure completes but the bot is not working.**
The azure extension used to deploy the code actually uses these steps and zips the folder according to the type of file **node/ c# /typescript** mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#52-zip-up-the-code-directory-manually. 
The problem according to me is the change in folder structure to transpile the ES6 code. In the new folder structure, index.js file now resides inside the ***src folder*** as compared to the default template solution of Nodejs where index.js reside in the root location. I am forced to change the structure because that is the only way to run the bot.

Please suggest the steps to deploy a bot to azure written in nodejs where transpilation of es6 using babel has been done.

Comment: I assume your azure app service is windows based in that case check your web.config file for iisnode handler path pointing to your new file path where index.js is located. <add name="iisnode" path="dist/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>

Comment: Bot Framework Node SDK officially supports ES6. You can refer to https://gist.github.com/mvalipour/75136095a164b57fc94fafebc34e0906 & https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-node-es2015-example